# How to select correct country from currency ISO code in C#

Tags: c#, localization

I am building an app where the user can input their currency via the ISO 4127 code (EUR,USD, JPY, etc).

As a eye-candy feature, I wanted to add a tooltip to the `TextBox` control where one could find some inforamtion about the currency, that is the translated name, the symbol and the native name.

For the translated and symbol all is good, I found all I need (I found an amazing repository with everything translated), but when it comes to the native name I got into an interesting a peculiar issue:

As an example, let's take the UK Pounds (ISO "GBP"). Using the methods available from the `CultureInfo` and `RegionInfo` class I get that there are 3 regions adopting the GBP:

1. the Welsch one, with `CurrencyNativeName` = "Punt Prydain"
2. the British one, with `CurrencyNativeName` = "Pound Sterling"
3. the Scottish one, with `CurrencyNativeName` = "Punnd Sasannach"

The question is: is there any "default international native name"? in this case, usually one means the british name, but all of these 3 region have as parent the "en" language.

This question does not intend to raise any political or regional issue at all, I'm just asking if there is a default value when somebody chooses a courrency used in multiple countries or regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new RegionInfo("GB").CurrencyNativeName` will get you the "default international native name" for the UK (which is "Pound Sterling"), where "GB" is the [two-letter code defined in ISO 3166](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo.twoletterisoregionname?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).